# Encode or Escape Strings in API Response to/from Database?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, rest, api

I am working in JavaScript.

I am currently querying a 3rd party API, which returns a string.

This string might contain for example the word: `it's`

I tried escaping it like: `it\'s` before inserting it into the database, however I was getting syntax issues in POSTGRESQL.

My solution instead was to instead convert the string to HTML entities using: [node-html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities)

Which would insert into database like: `it&apos;s`.

My API responses are ultimately sent back in JSON.

My question is... **Is it more common/acceptable to receive a string from an API response with slash escaped string, or an HTML encoded string?**

Comment: How are you inserting the row in the DB? This should be abstracted by the layer that interracts with the DB or the DB itself I would say.

Comment: "*I was getting syntax issues in POSTGRESQL*" - how were you constructing the sql query that inserts the value? Please show us that code which causes the error. Make sure to use parameterised queries, and you can store the plain string without having to do any escaping yourself.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much for pointing out parameterized queries. That did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tthe most acceptable way is receiving JSON from API response, and, according to JSON standard, `'` shouldn't be escaped, but `"` should:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({a: "it's", b:'hello "world"'}))
// {"a":"it's","b":"hello \"world\""}
```

Escaping values shouldn't be implemented manually. For one, if you are concatenating user data directly to mysql query you are exposing your server to sql injection attacks

It depends on which library you are using to connect to your database, in case of [node-postgres](http://node-postgres) read about parameterized query here https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Or, in case of [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: I just wanted to point out, the inspired solution from your answer was: parameterized queries. Thank you for your guidance.